# How to deploy a project on nexus without version and timestamp?

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a project which i want to deploy on nexus, due to requirements from above, I don't want the version, for example "myProject-2.3.war", I want myProject.war . 
I have already tried:

```
 <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
```

but this only results in the war file in target folder to be version-less, if i perform a mvn deploy to the repo the version still comes, my pom looks like this:

```
     <build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- web.xml is not mandatory since JavaEE 5 -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <overlays>
                    <overlay>
                        <groupId>{co-ordinates}</groupId>
                        <artifactId>myProject</artifactId>
                    </overlay>
                </overlays>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: In Nexus you can't change that. `<finalName>..</finalName>` is only for the target folder for nothing else....

Answer (score 0):

i could not find any way in maven that could do, what i required, so i am using FTP application like "curl" to manually deploy the artifact with the correct name, after correcting the name.